# using jquery to create a new form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a stepped form that has validations on each step.  So to submit the full form I created 2 methods to search through each step form grabbing all the elements to fill a hidden form on the page and submit that.  What I have works well for everything but check boxes.  It grabs the checkbox, adding it to the final form, regardless of whether or not it was checked.  This doesn't represent what is actually filled out.  So I am trying to modify what I have to only grab the check box elements if they are checked with no luck.

Here is what I have that works

```
function submitMainForm()
{
   $('#step1form, #step2form, #step3form').each(
    function(){ 
        $('#CompetitiveSave').append(getNamesAndValues($(this))); 
        });
    $('#CompetitiveSave').submit(); // submit the created form
}
```

which calls

```
function getNamesAndValues(jQObj)
{
    var divContainer = $(document.createElement('div'));
    var inputElement = $(document.createElement('input'));
    inputElement.attr('type', 'hidden');
    jQObj.each( function (){
        if (this.id){
            $(this).find('.FormLine').children().each(function(){
                    if (this.id && this.value){
                        inputElement.attr('name',this.name);
                        inputElement.attr('id',this.id);
                        inputElement.attr('value',this.value);
                        divContainer[0].appendChild(inputElement[0]);
                        inputElement = $(document.createElement('input'));
                        inputElement.attr('type','hidden');
                    }
                }
            );
        }

    });
    return divContainer.html();
}
```

It works perfectly, as it stands short of that it includes ALL checkboxes, whether they were checked or not.  Any pointers on what to change are very much appreciated

I had tried

```
function getNamesAndValues(jQObj)
{
    var divContainer = $(document.createElement('div'));
    var inputElement = $(document.createElement('input'));
    inputElement.attr('type', 'hidden');
    jQObj.each( function (){
        if(this.id)
        {
            $(this).find('.FormLine').children().each(function(){
                    if (this.id && this.value)//if it has an id and a value
                    {
                        if(this.type=='checkbox' && this.attr('checked') )//if it is a checkbox, it has to be checked to include
                        {
                          inputElement.attr('name',this.name);
                          inputElement.attr('id',this.id);
                          inputElement.attr('value',this.value);
                          divContainer[0].appendChild(inputElement[0]);
                          inputElement = $(document.createElement('input'));
                          inputElement.attr('type','hidden');

                        }
                        else if(this.type!='checkbox')//otherwise if it isn't a check box, include it
                        {
                            inputElement.attr('name',this.name);
                            inputElement.attr('id',this.id);
                            inputElement.attr('value',this.value);
                            divContainer[0].appendChild(inputElement[0]);
                            inputElement = $(document.createElement('input'));
                            inputElement.attr('type','hidden');
                        }
```

```
                }
            }
        );
    }        
});
return divContainer.html();
```

}
 But that didn't work

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you looked at the [jQuery Forms](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin, it may be helpful in this situation?

Comment: I am not trying to ajax the form, the user has the ability to step through 3 steps of a form, saving at any time or finalizing the form.
If they save, then I search through all the fields entered up to then and use them to fill a hidden form with is then submitted. It works great, except for checkboxes, it grabs them whether checked or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take extra care for checkbox, it may you need to add the line

```
inputElement.attr('checked',this.attr('checked'));
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe that would add the checked attribute to the inputElements, which I could see value in.  But wouldn't I need to insure that line only occurs if the element searched was a checkbox ?

Comment: I added it..
if (this.id && this.value){
 inputElement.attr('name',this.name);
 inputElement.attr('id',this.id);
if(this.type=='checkbox')InputElement.attr('checked',this.attr('checked'));
 inputElement.attr('value',this.value);
                        divContainer[0].appendChild(inputElement[0]);
  inputElement = $(document.createElement('input'));
  inputElement.attr('type','hidden'); }}

and it errors out: 
this.attr is not a function
inputElement.attr('checked',this.attr('checked'));

Comment: You can put your html. it might be something like this.parent.attr() or somewhat. This is the only way. You know your html I just put the way to do such things.